# XAMPP "MySQL shutdown unexpectedly" Win10

Tags: mysql, xampp, shutdown

> 7:23:46 PM  [main]    Initializing Control Panel
>
> 7:23:46 PM  [main]     Windows Version: Windows 8  64-bit
>
> 7:23:46 PM  [main]     XAMPP Version: 5.6.11
>
> 7:23:46 PM  [main]     Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
>
> 7:23:46 PM  [main]     You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
>
> 7:23:46 PM  [main]     most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
>
> 7:23:46 PM  [main]     there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think
>
> 7:23:46 PM  [main]     about running this application with administrator rights!
>
> 7:23:46 PM  [main]     XAMPP Installation Directory: "e:\xampp\"
>
> 7:23:46 PM  [main]     Checking for prerequisites
>
> 7:23:46 PM  [main]     All prerequisites found
>
> 7:23:46 PM  [main]     The Apache module is disabled
>
> 7:23:46 PM  [main]     The FileZilla module is disabled
>
> 7:23:46 PM  [main]     The Mercury module is disabled
>
> 7:23:46 PM  [main]     The Tomcat module is disabled
>
> 7:23:46 PM  [main]     Enabling autostart for module "MySQL"
>
> 7:23:46 PM  [main]     Starting Check-Timer
>
> 7:23:46 PM  [main]     Control Panel Ready
>
> 7:23:47 PM  [mysql]    Autostart active: starting...
>
> 7:23:47 PM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL app...
>
> 7:23:47 PM  [mysql]    Status change detected: running
>
> 7:23:48 PM  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped
>
> 7:23:48 PM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> 7:23:48 PM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
>
> 7:23:48 PM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>
> 7:23:48 PM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>
> 7:23:48 PM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 7:23:48 PM  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
>
> 7:23:48 PM  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums

I had everything working yesterday, but for some reason I can't get it to work now.  I tried deleting and reinstalling the xampp file.  It says I'm not running admin rights, but I'm the only user and admin.  I've tried a few suggestions already posted on here, but I cannot get it to work.  Any ideas?

> 2015-08-18 21:07:18 4436 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>
> 2015-08-18 21:07:18 2988 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>
> 2015-08-18 21:07:18 4436 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
>
> 2015-08-18 21:07:18 4436 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 2015-08-18 21:07:18 4436 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows 
>   interlocked functions
>
> 2015-08-18 21:07:18 4436 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
>
> 2015-08-18 21:07:18 4436 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>
> 2015-08-18 21:07:18 4436 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
>
> 2015-08-18 21:07:18 4436 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
>
> 2015-08-18 21:07:18 4436 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 2015-08-18 21:07:19 4436 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is 
>   Barracuda.
>
> 2015-08-18 21:07:23 4436 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
>
> 2015-08-18 21:07:23 4436 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 2015-08-18 21:07:23 4436 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.25 started; log sequence number 1665234
>
> 2015-08-18 21:07:23 4436 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
>
> 2015-08-18 21:07:23 4436 [Note] IPv6 is available.
>
> 2015-08-18 21:07:23 4436 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
>
> 2015-08-18 21:07:23 4436 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
>
> 2015-08-18 21:07:25 4436 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
>
> 2015-08-18 21:07:25 4436 [Note] mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
>
> Version: '5.6.25'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: I restarted my computer and noticed that there was an update available.  Once I did the update and restarted, completely deleted xampp and reinstalled, MySQL is functioning correctly again.  Perhaps because there was an update available, it wasn't letting it run?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my computer and noticed that there was an update available. Once I did the update and restarted, completely deleted xampp and reinstalled, MySQL is functioning correctly again. Perhaps because there was an update available, it wasn't letting it run?

TL;DR: Check for updates, restart computer, reinstall xampp.  MySQL should work.